# Can't setup Tomcat 6 in Eclipse - "Could not load the Tomcat server configuration" error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

For the last couple of hours, I'm desperately trying to configure apache tomcat6 in Eclipse, and I'm having some difficulties.
I tried everything I could find online, including several posts here in Stack Overflow (most of the problems I found wasn't exactly like mine).
Initially, I followed [this tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java-ee/how-to-configure-apache-tomcat-in-eclipse-ide/), and after installing tomcat6 like this:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat6-common
sudo apt-get install tomcat6
```

and making sure that the server is running.
Next, I followed the mentioned tutorial, and everything was fine, until I got to stage 5.4 in the tutorial: "Start Server".
When I click Start, I get the following error:
[image]

As I said, I tried to look online for an answer, but nothing seems to help...
Does anyone know why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: These answers are solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, after 3 and a half hours of trying...
Apparently, when I installed tomcat from the command line (sudo-apt-get etc) the `/usr/share/tomcat6` folder (the default installation path) was missing some files, including this `/conf` folder, which required for Eclipse (hence the error message).
But when I removed it, and download tomcat as a `tar.gz` file from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi), and extracted it, it somehow contains more files in it, including the `/conf` folder.
So then in Eclipse I created a new Server, and provided the path of the new extracted folder, instead of the previous `/usr/share/tomcat`.
This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long-shot but do you have correct permissions for the folder where the config file is located?

Comment: Where is the config file location? in `/usr/share/tomcat6` I don't have any config file (or folder...)

Answer (score 0):

try to follow the steps mentioned in below link

[clipse-could-not-load-the-tomcat-server-configuration](http://lucasterdev.altervista.org/wordpress/2012/05/12/could-not-load-the-tomcat-server-configuration-at-serverstomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-config-the-configuration-may-be-corrupt-or-incomplet/)

1)Close Eclipse

2)Copy all files from TOMCAT_6_HOME/conf to WORKSPACE_FOLDER/Servers/Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config

3)Start Eclipse

4) Expand the Servers project, click on the Tomcat 6 project and hit F5

5) Start Tomcat from Eclipse

Comment: here in 4th steps means you need to refresh as F5 will not work in your OS,

Comment: I also found this link, but I don't have a `/conf` folder in my `/usr/share/tomcat6` folder... where is this `/conf` folder suppose to be?

Comment: OK, found it here: 
`/home/****/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/conf/tomcat-users.xml` this is probably from my first attempts at downloading and installing tomcat (initially I downloaded the 8'th version and later downloaded and installed the 6)

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the server using terminal and then try in eclipse. go to /bin/ execute the command startup.sh. try this.

if you still got error. Execute this configtest.sh will provide you the proper error.

Then try set Classpath for your server. can be done using setclasspath.sh

Comment: When I try to restart the server with:  
`/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/shutdown.sh` and then `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh` the second command (the startup.sh) gives some weird error saying: 
`touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/catalina.out’: No such file or directory
/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh: 371: /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat6/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent`
 what is it about?