# could not load the tomcat server error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

I want to run my dynamic project on tomcat 8 server, but I receive the below error.

I searched it and found [Can't setup Tomcat 6 in Eclipse - "Could not load the Tomcat server configuration" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079887/cant-setup-tomcat-6-in-eclipse-could-not-load-the-tomcat-server-configuratio).

I copy tomcat/conf file as telling in here but it is not allowed to copy. How to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: there is a problem with your tomcat config or port

Comment: ı try to change port in conf but it is not allowed. Server.xml is not opening

Comment: could you please check your tomcat bit and os bit are they same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Tomcat was installed in /opt/Tomcat path. So ubuntu prevents to copy from the path by eclipse. I again installed Tomcat in my document. Now, eclipse does not give any error.